# Palindrome function using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, palindrome

I cant see where i've gone wrong here , its working for some palindromes but not working for others.

Basically the program takes in a word , the length of the word and then returns if it is a palindrome or is not a palindrome , and the function must use recursion.

```
bool palindrome(char a[],int length){
 int start = *a;
 if (*a != a[length-1])
    return false;

 if (*a == a[length-1]||start<length)
    return true;

 else 
    return palindrome(a+1,length-1);

 return false;
}
```

Can anyone see any problems with this function?

Comment: Try [explaining every line of your code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). This is a very short piece of code, shouldn't take long. I'll bet anything that your rubber duck will figure out the problem. Heck, my rubber duck found the problem in five seconds.

Comment: haha , i feel like its something stupid  , ill get my rubber duck now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My duck says you are very close.  He says you need to forget about whatever you were trying to do with `start` and that each recursion reduces length by 2, not 1 (because the first character is paired with its match, the last character).  Then he showed me this:

```
bool palindrome(const char* a, int length) {
    if(length < 2) return true;
    if(a[0] != a[length-1]) return false;
    return palindrome(a+1, length - 2);
}
```

Comment: I got it there myself ! stupid mistake , tell your duck thanks!

Comment: He responded "Quack!"